# used ajax call in jquery to get the values of check box but values are not passed into action result

Tags: jquery, ajax

For example, if the checkbox is checked, then I need to get that value and passed to controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('input:submit').click(function () {
    var allVals = [];
    debugger;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/ApplyWithdraw',
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'ids': 'allVals' },
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
   });
});
```

mvc action result in homecontroller page

```
public ActionResult ApplyWithdraw(int[] ids)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass variable value and not a string,

You have,

```
data: { 'ids': 'allVals' },
```

But it should be,

```
data: { 'ids': allVals },
```

Answer (score 1):

`data: { 'ids': 'allVals' },` allVals is a `variable` here. pass it as

`data: { 'ids': allVals },`

Answer (score 1):

Here Is the Corrected Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('input:submit').click(function () {
    var allVals = [];
    debugger;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/ApplyWithdraw',
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'ids': allVals },
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
   });
});
```